# URL jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would want to post data to my "mail.py" script. But I don't know the URL to that file.

My jQuery AJAX code and this javascript file is placed in

```
RKProjects/scripts_js/contactform.js
```

My python script is placed in

```
RKProjects/scripts_js/mail.py
```

Here is my jQuery ajax code (without the URL)

```
var toPost = {
    voornaamPost: document.getElementById('fnameInput').value,
    achternaamPost: document.getElementById('lnameInput').value,
    gsmPost: document.getElementById('gsmInput').value,
    mailPost: document.getElementById('emailInput').value,
    berichtPost: document.getElementById('berichtInput').value
   };

var jsonToPost = JSON.stringify(toPost);



$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:'',
    data: toPost,
    success: function(){
        alert('succes')
    },
    error:  function (){
        alert('error')
    }
})
```

Comment: You can't send POST requests to a file. You must create a server, for Python try [Flask](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). After the server started, you can send POST (and more) requests at the URL (commonly in dev mode at *localhost*) and PORT (commonly in dev mode at *8080*).

Comment: Take a look a [this](https://kite.com/blog/python/flask-restful-api-tutorial/) tutorial. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the URL where to send the request to, otherwise it will point to the URL of the page you are on.

You have the following options:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/path/mail.py', // absolute
});

$.ajax({
    url: '/path/mail.py', // relative to root
});
```

If you add the URL without the first "/" it will just append whatever you have to the URL of the page you are on.

Comment: If I use this url I get the error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".

Comment: Sorry, my instructions were wrong, I've revised my answer.